# Magento echo attribute

Tags: magento

I have a problem with my magento. I want echo some attribute, it works fine but why this return number and not text?. For example it return number 7, but I want text sold Out.

```
<?php print $_product->getCustomStockStatus(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('custom_stock_status');
```